# how to use fbox in align mode

Tags: math-mode, boxes

I'm trying to highlight the diagonal elements of a matrix by using `fbox` but I failed. I've searched for the problem, some ppl suggest using tikz. I don't want to use it, so I decided to use `fbox{}`.  Every time I do the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       \sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{yx}        \\
       \sigma_{xy} & \fbox{\sigma_{yy}} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

it throws an error `!Argument of \align has an extra}`
if I remove `\sigma_{}`, it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `\boxed` and not `\fbox`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\fbox` sets its argument in text mode, and `\sigma` as well as the subscript requires math mode. So, use `\fbox{$\sigma_{yy}$}` or the `\boxed` version supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
  \boxed{\sigma_{xx}} & \sigma_{yx}          \\
  \sigma_{xy}         & \fbox{$\sigma_{yy}$}
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Also, there's no need for `align` here, and I'd rather use an `equation` (if you want it numbered) or `\[`...`\]` if not.

Comment: Which is exactly the same as using `\boxed` from `amsmath`, `\boxed{...} = \fbox{$...$}` (almost)

Comment: @daleif `\boxed` also issues `\displaystyle` while `\fbox{$...$}` would be in `\textstyle`.